# PyCharm Debugger Stuck on "Collecting Data"

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

So I installed the free version of PyCharm professional last week and have been encountering the problem where I am debugging code on a remote server and when I try to display variables, it simply says "collecting data" and then if I try to continue the debugging process PyCharm breaks.

I have been researching solutions and I have Gevent compatible enabled as well as tried all 3 variable settings; Synchronously, Asynchronously, and On Demand.

I should also note that I am running into a problem where the debugger is skipping all my break points as well and I have to restart my server connection in order to get the break points to hit (and sometimes it takes a couple of tries)

I know that it is entirely possible to see the variables that are collecting data as one of my co-workers who recommended PyCharm has no problem, and there was 1 run where I was able to see the variables, but when I re-ran the commands (with absolutely no change), I was back at square one.

I've been going through PyCharm forums and it seems as if this has been a reoccurring issue for a handful of years now, but knowing that it worked once for me, and it works for my coworker, am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just recently my PyCharm has started to behave this way as well.  I researched and tried the same solutions you did, to no avail.  On certain projects it simply hangs forever on "collecting data" - projects that used to work - where code hasn't changed.  Pls let me know if you find anything else; I will keep researching and testing as well

EDIT: FWIW.  In my particular case I isolated the cause of this (at least I think).  I had a very large dataframe in memory and if this DF is not in memory, the debugger does not hang.  None of my watches were explicitly on this DF, but I guess the debugger needed to inspect it upon break and the object was just too big somehow.  Note that it hung even if "variables loading policy" was set to "on demand", so the debugger still must automatically investigate all variables somehow.